# Mock connection to RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-amqp, junit5

I have a Spring application with Spring AMQP. I want to run JUnit test which starts Spring with H2 database.

But for Spring AMQP I get this exception during startup:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpAdmin]: Factory method 'amqpAdmin' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
        ... 83 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Is there some way to mockup the connection to RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 3):

The [`RabbitMQ-mock`](https://github.com/fridujo/rabbitmq-mock) library might be of help, it mocks the `ConnectionFactory` in order to provide a mocked connection. A working example of an integration test can be found [here](https://github.com/fridujo/rabbitmq-mock/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/fridujo/rabbitmq/mock/spring/SpringIntegrationTest.java).

Comment: Maybe I ne3ed to set connection properties into the application.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

you can use apache qpid https://qpid.apache.org/ as mock in your tests
just create Broker in test context

```
private final Broker broker = new Broker();
public EmbeddedAMQPBroker() throws Exception {
    final String configFileName = "qpid-config.json";
    final String passwordFileName = "passwd.properties";
    // prepare options
    final BrokerOptions brokerOptions = new BrokerOptions();
    brokerOptions.setConfigProperty("qpid.amqp_port", String.valueOf(BROKER_PORT));
    brokerOptions.setConfigProperty("qpid.pass_file", findResourcePath(passwordFileName));
    brokerOptions.setConfigProperty("qpid.work_dir", Files.createTempDir().getAbsolutePath());
    brokerOptions.setInitialConfigurationLocation(findResourcePath(configFileName));
    // start broker
    broker.startup(brokerOptions);
}
```

it will construct your local AMQP message broker and you can use it without RabbitMQ environment

or if you want just to mock objects without providing functionality you can ude Mockito framework

Comment: also best option is to use testcontainers